# jenkins git how pull instead of clone?

Tags: git, jenkins

How can I configure jenkins that it pull instead of clone?

[image]

Comment: Pull and clone are not mutually exclusive options (you can't pull unless you're in a repo, and you need clone to get a repo). So could you clarify your intent here?

Answer (score 5):

The default behavior of git plugin in jenkins is:

1. Clone the repository if your directory is empty;
2. If the repository has already been cloned, it will be updated.

So, the first time that your job run the repository will be cloned, and in the second will be updated.

Comment: @mu無 as far as I remember, jenkins will do a `fetch`